# Not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, timestamp

I have been working with a dataframe that contains some date values. These date values contain years, months and days like 1965-07-19. Now i try to categorize them by year for every ten years, meaning that 1960 - 1969 is labled as 1960's in a new column 'Year' and so on. My problem is that i get the error **"'<'** **not supported between instances of 'Timestamp' and 'str' "**, while i have converted it to date_time pandas dataframe.

Example of my df:

| Event | Event.Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1961-10-24 |
| 1 | 1972-07-19 |
| 2 | 1989-08-02 |
| 3 | 2022-12-26 |

what i want:

| Event | Event.Date | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1961-10-24 | 1960's |
| 1 | 1972-07-19 | 1970's |
| 2 | 1989-08-02 | 1980's |
| 3 | 2022-12-26 | 2010's |

The code I have been working on is:

```
#To datetime
df['Event.Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Event.Date'])

cat_date = []
for dt in df["Event.Date"]:
    if dt < '1960-01-01' : cat_lft.append("1950's")
    elif dt < '1970-01-01': cat_lft.append("1960's")
    elif dt < '1980-01-01': cat_lft.append("1970's")
    elif dt < '1990-01-01': cat_lft.append("1980's")
    elif dt < '2000-01-01': cat_lft.append("1990's")
    elif dt < '2010-01-01': cat_lft.append("2000's")
    elif dt < '2023-01-01': cat_lft.append("2010's")
    else: cat_dt.append("nan")
        
# List as column (append)
df["Year"] = cat_date
```

Anyone who knows what i have been doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import pandas as pd
    
data = {'Event': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3},
        'Event.Date': {0: '1961-10-24',
                       1: '1972-07-19',
                       2: '1989-08-02',
                       3: '2022-12-26'}}
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Event.Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Event.Date'])

print(df)
```

```
   Event  Event.Date
0      0  1961-10-24
1      1  1972-07-19
2      2  1989-08-02
3      3  2022-12-26
```

```py
df['Year'] = (df['Event.Date'].dt.year // 10 * 10).astype(str) + "'s"
print(df)
```

```
   Event Event.Date    Year
0      0 1961-10-24  1960's
1      1 1972-07-19  1970's
2      2 1989-08-02  1980's
3      3 2022-12-26  2020's
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting the column to a `datetime`, round the year to the decade and format the result:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Event.Date': ['1961-10-24', '1972-07-19', '1989-08-02', '2022-12-26']})
df['Event.Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Event.Date'])
df['Year'] = (df['Event.Date'].dt.year // 10 * 10).apply(lambda x: f"{x}'s")
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Event.Date    Year
0 1961-10-24  1960's
1 1972-07-19  1970's
2 1989-08-02  1980's
3 2022-12-26  2020's
```